# Why base64 encoded image is not shown in Google Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, base64

I have the next b64 encoded image returned from a server:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,TU0AKgAFeZhykYz/cpGM/3KRjP9ykYz/cpGM/3KRjP9ykYz/cpGM/3OSjf9zko3/dJOO/3ST....///zJgAAB5IAAP2R///7ov///aMAAAPcAADAbA==" />
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bPoEEB

The image is properly rendered in the Safari, but is not displayed in Chrome and Firefox.

Also I tried to render it in the canvas, but the issue is still.

And this issue concerns not only this particular image, but all that are returned from the server.

So, what could be the problem?

Comment: please check if the base64 string is valid. How are you generating this base64 string?

Comment: I have checked it, it's correct. I get it from server.